# Get current user log in signal in Django

Tags: django, django-admin, django-users

I am just using the admin site in Django. I have 2 Django signals (pre_save and post_save). I would like to have the username of the current user. How would I do that? It does not seem I can send a request Or I did not understand it.

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you are using the admin site why not use a custom model admin

```
class MyModelAdmin( admin.ModelAdmin ):
    def save_model( self, request, obj, form, change ):
        #pre save stuff here
        obj.save()
        #post save stuff here



admin.site.register( MyModel, MyModelAdmin )
```

A signal is something that is fired every time the object is saved regardless of if it is being done by the admin or some process that isn't tied to a request and isn't really an appropriate place to be doing request based actions

Comment: In Feb, 2015. Is this still the only way to get user's request in Django signal?

Comment: This is the correct answer, coupled with [ModelAdmin.exclude](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.exclude) for required prepopulated fields is very useful.

Comment: This will work for some but not all cases, e.g. changes to `m2m` relationships can only be hooked via signals.

Answer (score 39):

Being reluctant to mess around with thread-local state, I decided to try a different approach. As far as I can tell, the `post_save` and `pre_save` signal handlers are called synchronously in the thread that calls `save()`. If we are in the normal request handling loop, then we can just walk up the stack to find the request object as a local variable somewhere. e.g.

```
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(pre_save)
def my_callback(sender, **kwargs):
    import inspect
    for frame_record in inspect.stack():
        if frame_record[3]=='get_response':
            request = frame_record[0].f_locals['request']
            break
    else:
        request = None
    ...
```

If there's a current request, you can grab the `user` attribute from it.

Note: like it says in the `inspect` module docs,

> This function relies on Python stack frame support in the interpreter, which isn’t
>   guaranteed to exist in all implementations of Python.

Comment: You sir, are a legend. Brilliant solution, works just as advertised.

Comment: pros and cons of this approach ?

Comment: **Pros** - Does work, simpler to implement and avoids thread locals (may or may not be a bad thing)

**Cons** - Performance hit (has to scan the call stack potentially for each signal), won't work via tests - you will need to add additional logic to extract request objects from your tests

Comment: I have changed it to reversed(inspect.stack()) cos  from overal 62 iteration in my Django project get_response is found on iteration 49, which tells us that scan in reverced direction should be more profitable.

Comment: The time to reverse de whole 62 items + scan the ~10 first is **slower** than scan the ~49 first. Do some tests with timeit. But I'm surprised how few difference there is.

Comment: Good quick solution!

Answer (score 3):

You can use a middleware to store the current user: http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2179/

Then you would be able to get the user with `get_current_user()`

Comment: That solution relies on Thread Locals.  Those are considered 'bad' for various reasons.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3227180/why-is-using-thread-locals-in-django-bad

Comment: Just a comment on what @AaronC.deBruyn said - the link he posted actually disagrees with his statement, and popular opinion concludes the use of thread locals for this purpose **is acceptable**.

Answer (score 2):

We can solve this problem using middleware classes.
Create singleton class in where will be storing user variable.

```
class Singleton(type):
    '''
        Singleton pattern requires for GetUser class
    '''
    def __init__(cls, name, bases, dicts):
        cls.instance = None

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls.instance is None:
            cls.instance = super(Singleton, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        return cls.instance 


class NotLoggedInUserException(Exception):
    '''
    '''
    def __init__(self, val='No users have been logged in'):
        self.val = val
        super(NotLoggedInUser, self).__init__()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.val

class LoggedInUser(object):
    __metaclass__ = Singleton

    user = None

    def set_user(self, request):
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            self.user = request.user

    @property
    def current_user(self):
        '''
            Return current user or raise Exception
        '''
        if self.user is None:
            raise NotLoggedInUserException()
        return self.user

    @property
    def have_user(self):
    return not user is None
```

Create own middleware class that will be setting user for LoggedInUser instance,and insert out middleware after 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware' in settings.py

```
from useranytimeaccess import LoggedInUser
class LoggedInUserMiddleware(object):
    '''
        Insert this middleware after django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware
    '''
    def process_request(self, request):
        '''
            Returned None for continue request
        '''
        logged_in_user = LoggedInUser()
        logged_in_user.set_user(request)
        return None
```

In signals import LoggedInUser class and get current user

```
logged_in = LoggedInUser()
user = logged_in.user
```

Answer (score 0):

Will I do it like this I am still looking for a better solution if I am not using the admin site

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=FlowList)
def flow_list_post_save(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
     import inspect
     request = None
     try:
        request = next((frame[0].f_locals['request'] for frame in inspect.stack() if frame[3] == 'get_response'), None)
     except StopIteration:
            pass
```