# Django, locale and thread locals

Tags: python, django, thread-local-storage

Is there a problem with Django using thread locals for localization (see `django.utils.translation.activate` for instance), especially when running on particular webservers?

Is it thus a limitation for the choice of servers on which a django project could run?

Btw, I am surprised to read in some places that using thread locals is not a good idea with Django when Django is  already doing it by itself...

**Update** (re-wording to make a difference with [Why is using thread locals in Django bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3227180)):
Is the current implementation "risky" with respect to some web servers on which to run Django? And is Django going to evolve to something thread-agnostic?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is using thread locals in Django bad?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3227180/why-is-using-thread-locals-in-django-bad)

Comment: @Louis sort of a duplicate, but I want to insist on the fact that Django itself is already using thread locals. I rather wonder when is the current implementation risky, if it can be? And is it going to stay as such?