# pseudo-globals in Flask and others

Tags: python, flask

I'm looking for a reasonable answer to this question:

https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=4207314

> I have no doubt that if I dug into it then it would all make sense, but my first instinct is this: how much of this complexity (proxy objects to thread locals, context stacks etc) results from the fact that doing:
>
> ```
>     from flask import request
> ```
>
> is just a bad idea?
>
> Perhaps things would be easier if instead of:
>
> ```
>     from flask import request
>
>     ...
>
>     @app.route('/'):
>     def index():
>         return "Hello from %s" % request.args.get('name')
> ```
>
> we did:
>
> ```
>     @app.route('/'):
>     def index(request):
>         return "Hello from %s" % request.args.get('name')
> ```

Armin's response the the above is not very satisfying:

> I was a huge opponent of thread locals for a really long time but I finally had to acknowledge that they make things easier instead of harder.
>
> ...
>
> The fact that you can do `_app_ctx_stack.top.mydatabase_connection` to get a database connection from anywhere is very helpful.
>
> ...
>
> TL;DR: you can't live without thread locals or you have a horrible API.

I don't see how `_app_ctx_stack.top.mydatabase_connection` is any better than `request.app.my_database_connection`.

Comment: Take into account that with an explicit argument, you now have to pass `requests` to any and all utility functions your views may need to use than need access to the request state. This includes 3rd party libraries.

Comment: I cannot understand this library argument that gets repeated.  *Of course* you have to pass arguments to a library function.  What is the alternative?  That a 3rd-party library does `from flask import request` and now depends on flask?

Comment: If you have to pass in a `request` argument, the library depends, at a bare minimum, on Werkzeug *already*. What I am talking about is *several layers* of calls, where view-related code is ultimately being called. Now you need a means to pass through the `request` object, or be able to access the response that'll be produced, but any and all 3rd party libraries along that path have to cooperate.

Comment: In any case, you can try out working with both Pyramid and Flask to see the difference. And then you find that even [Pyramid offers access to a thread-local 'current request' object](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/threadlocals.html). I have been coding web apps with Python for 15 years and I find that not having to pass request through several layers of calls tremendously helpful, even after being very resistant to the idea at first.

Comment: Is it possible you've been doing it wrong for 15 years?

Comment: You misunderstand me; Flask's approach is the newer approach here. I've been deeply involved in the development of Zope (and by extension, Plone, and more limited with Pyramid), so I do have some insights into the framework side of things, as well as their practical application.

Comment: But you use your 15 years of experience in support of an arguably poor design.

Comment: I am arguing that the design is pragmatic and in practice, *works*. Both approaches have their merits. What experience do you bring to dis it out of hand?

Comment: So nothing more than a short cut.  Worse is better.  Very well.

Comment: Sometimes practicality beats purity. Flask is just explicit about it, but just about all other frameworks use thread locals too! Bottle, Zope (and more so Plone), And Pyramid do. For Django there is a popular piece of middleware (also see http://stackoverflow.com/q/3227180). But Armin made it an explicit API choice and is somehow worse?

Answer (score 1):

you shouldn't only think in controllers (where you can access the request object). It's important also in other layers of your application (imagine a reusable service layer where there are important business rules)