# How can I access to request.header in post_delete of models.signals

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

In post_delete of models.signals, I want send a request to other server to notify about this action, but I have a problem when I try to get some info from request.headers(ex: clientId send from client), please help me about this problem
Thank you.

Comment: You could try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58153911/use-django-request-session-inside-utility-function/58154014#58154014

Comment: I think this is the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why do you want to use the request headers in the post_delete of models.signals? If the request headers are relevant, it suggests addressing your use case at the view level if that's practical...

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: you can't access request in a signal by the means of Django. If you absolutely need that, you can use some libraries that provide global access to the request object.

I suggest using this library: [django-middleware-global-request](https://pypi.org/project/django-middleware-global-request/). But make sure that there is no native django solutuion first.