# Is storing data in "thread local storage" in a Django application safe, in cases of concurrent requests?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, python-multithreading

I have seen at many places that using thread local storage to store any data in Django application is not a good practice.
But this is the only way I could store my request object. I need to store it because my application has a complex structure. And I can't keep on passing the request object at each function call or class intialization.

I need the cookies and headers from my request object, to be passed to some api calls I'm making at different places in the application.

I'm using this for reference:
https://blndxp.wordpress.com/2016/03/04/django-get-current-user-anywhere-in-your-code-using-a-middleware/

So I'm using a middleware, as mentioned in the reference.
And, this is how request is stored

```
from threading import local
_thread_locals = local()
_thread_locals.request = request
```

And, this is how data is fetched:

```
getattr(_thread_locals, "request", None)
```

So does are the data stored in the threads local to that particular request ? Or if another request takes place at the same time, does both of them use the same data ?(Which is certainly not what i want)

Or is there any new way of dealing with this old problem(storing request object globally)

Note: I'm also using `async` at places in my Django application(If that matters).

Comment: You seem to have misunderstood why TLS exists. It is not an appropriate solution for your problem.

Comment: Why is it not an appropriate solution?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Yes, using thread-local storage in Django is safe.

**Django uses one thread to handle each request. Django also uses thread-local data itself, for instance for [storing the currently activated locale](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/middleware/#module-django.middleware.locale). While appservers such as [Gunicorn](https://gunicorn.org/) and [uwsgi](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) can be configured to utilize multiple threads, each request will still be handled by a single thread.**

However, [there have been conflicting opinions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3227180/why-is-using-thread-locals-in-django-bad) on whether using thread-locals is an elegant and well-designed solution. The reasons against using thread-locals boil down to the same reasons why global variables are considered bad practice. [This answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/148154) discusses a number of them.

Still, storing the `request` object in thread-local data has become a widely used pattern in the Django community. There is even an app [Django-CRUM](https://django-crum.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) that contains a `CurrentRequestUserMiddleware` class and the functions `get_current_user()` and `get_current_request()`.

Note that as of version 3.0, Django has started to implement [asynchronous support](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/async/). I'm not sure what its implications are for apps like Django-CRUM. For the foreseeable future, however, thread-locals can safely be used with Django.

Comment: Thank You for your Answer, I had anyway handled it in a different way for now.
I required the cookies and headers from initial requests for passing it on to the some requests made inside my app.

And all these requests were made from a different class(named `Communication`). So I added the `cookies` and `headers` from initial request as  `static` variables of the `Communication Class`. And use this whenever a request is made from the same class.

Comment: It might be worth noting that with asyncio support added, it might not be possible anymore to do this. At least according to a Django Forum mod: https://forum.djangoproject.com/t/django-and-multi-tenancy-issue/18730/4