# How to create a log database in django to record the user that created, updated or deleted an object?

Tags: django

I want to record the user in a database who created, updated or deleted an object there using django.  I've found a simple solution with `threadlocal` and a logging abstract class from here : [Why is using thread locals in Django bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3227180/why-is-using-thread-locals-in-django-bad) ( but that is discouraged ).

But the problem with this solution is that it is extremely difficult to write any unit test.  So what would be a better solution for logging event based information about a user who created, updated, or deleted an object in django?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try django-simple-history. (https://django-simple-history.readthedocs.io/en/latest/querying_history.html)

It provides an history in django admin or querying history from python code

Comment: This solves most of the problem, though each time user that manipulates the object must be assigned manually. The package keeps all the history which is really useful. Thanks a lot, I cannot find anything better than this.